# How to get taggable friends list in c# windows 8 phone app?

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-8, facebook-c#-sdk

I want to get friends list in c# windows 8 phone app. I refered this link http://facebooksdk.net/docs/phone/controls/friendpicker-ui-control/ but i am getting only those friends who are using my app. How can i get taggable friend list?

Comment: Why down grade? I didn't asked wrong question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/user/taggable_friends

This is how to get taggable friends, with example code.

That friendpicker probably does not use `taggable_friends`, but the user friends with the `/me/friends` endpoint. And that one only returns friends who authorized your App too, since April 2014. See changelog for more information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog